# how to use firebase token authentication with a web api2 controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, token

I have a firebase authentication token that i am trying to pass to a web api controller. I am following this post here. [stackoverflowpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745355/spa-firebase-and-net-webapi-2-authentication#)

I have the bearer token in the $http request headers.
[image: angular]

I took care of cors(unless I missed something). The end point in my api project is receiving the request with null headers. So I am trying to debug what is wrong but without any specific errors I am not sure where to look
[image: apiproject]

Comment: could you post the network calls and results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of an element "Authorization" in header by using following code:

```
  string firebaseAuthToken = string.Empty;
    firebaseAuthToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").First();
```

Comment: coming up not found. {"The given header was not found."}